# cannot convert void to "classname"

Tags: java, networking, tcp

im trying to create a class that is a thread that can be stored in an array, which will make it easier for me to handle user inputs from clients to the server.

here is my PongPlayerThread

```
package Pong;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class PongPlayerThread extends Thread 
{
private Socket socket = null;
private String pongData = "";

public PongPlayerThread() 
{
    //clear
}

public PongPlayerThread(Socket socket, int id, String data) 
{
    //super("PongPlayerThread");
    pongData = data;
    this.socket = socket;
}

public void passData(String data)
{
    pongData = data;
}

public void run()
{
    try
    {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        while(true)
        {
            out.println(pongData);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

now in this line on my server where a client can connect

```
players[0] = new PongPlayerThread(serverSocket.accept(), 0, rtnInfo()).start();
```

I get this error
"cannot convert from void to PongPlayerThread" why is that? I have searched but it is quite hard when you get the error with your classname.

I now have this code

```
        players[idPlayer] = new PongPlayerThread(serverSocket.accept(), idPlayer, rtnInfo());
        players[idPlayer].start();
```

but when a client connects i get this error 
Pong
400.0:301.0:60.0:300.0:740.0:300.0
Server started
Server was setup and will try to create a socket
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Pong.PongServer.main(PongServer.java:82)

the line it is pointing at is 
    players[idPlayer] = new PongPlayerThread(serverSocket.accept(), idPlayer, rtnInfo());
???

Answer (score 5):

```
players[0] = new PongPlayerThread(serverSocket.accept(), 0, rtnInfo());
players[0].start();
```

Comment: ok, when i now run my code i get this
Pong
400.0:301.0:60.0:300.0:740.0:300.0
Server started
Server was setup and will try to create a socket
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Pong.PongServer.main(PongServer.java:82)

if you want the code for the server just say

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that Thread.start() returns void, and you are trying to assign the result of `new PPT(...).start()` to `players[0]`.

`new PPT(...).start()` returns void, and so the compiler is complaining that it can't convert this void into an object of type PongPlayerThread.